# Adding support for flair to reddit_api

Tags: python, api, reddit

I'm trying to add support for [reddit flair api](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API%3A-flair) to [reddit_api](https://github.com/mellort/reddit_api), but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

I've added the following to `urls.py`:

```
  ("api/", {
            ...
            "flair": "flair/"
           }),
```

And the following to `reddit.py`:

```
@require_login
def set_flair(self, subreddit, user, text='', css_class=''):
    """Set flair of user in given subreddit"""
    url = urls["flair"]
    params = {'r': subreddit,
              'user': user,
              'text': text,
              'css_class': css_class,
              'uh': self.modhash}
    return self._request_json(url, params)
```

But my code seems to have no discernable effect:

```
import reddit

r = reddit.Reddit(user_agent='User rating modifier')
r.login(user='xxxx', password='xxxx')
r.set_flair('subreddit', 'username', 'textflair', 'cssclass')
```

I don't get an error, but the user flair isn't added on reddit. The other features of `reddit_api` work perfectly for me, and I have all the right moderator permissions on reddit. Have I gone wrong somewhere with my code?

Comment: Did you try raising an exception?

Comment: This support along with other flair options have been officially added to the [reddit_api](https://github.com/mellort/reddit_api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working `set_flair` function:

```
@require_login
def set_flair(self, subreddit, user, text='', css_class=''):
    """Set flair of user in given subreddit"""
    url = urls["flair"]
    params = {'r': subreddit,
              'name': user,
              'text': text,
              'css_class': css_class,
              'uh': self.user.modhash}
    return self._request_json(url, params)
```

First error I've got after running your code was `.error.USER_REQUIRED` ("please login to do that"). API [specifically states](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API%3a-flair) that user's modhash is required. So I've changed `self.modhash` to `self.user.modhash`.

The second error was `.error.NO_USER.field-name`. And it was just a matter of changing `user` parameter to `name`.